# Java Scanner Validation - Char, int, double, String

Tags: java

How can I display different messages for different types of data that are entered?
I only want a user to be able to enter an integer, but if they enter something else then I want a custom message for each type.
For example,

- char : "You can't enter a letter, please use a number from 1-10"
- double: "You can't enter a number with a decimal, please use a whole number from 1-10"
- string: "Please enter a number from 1-10"

Currently I am using this code which only lets me display one message if it's not an integer

```
printMenuOption();
if (!sc.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 1 to 10");
    sc.nextLine();
}else{
    returnDataMenu(sc.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about characteristics of each which would help you make the determination? For example, a char would be size of 1 and non-numeric, and so on.

Comment: You can check for `sc.hasNextDouble()` and after you read `sc.nextLine()` you can check if it has 1 character or not.

Comment: Have you thought about using instanceof?

Comment: @AdrianM., how would calling instanceof help?

Comment: Well, it might not; I was thinking that if he were able to test the input with, say, input instanceof Double ? ... : ..., then he could determine which message to output.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that's a good idea, I have implemented that, however now it's not continuing with the class after it outputs the error message.

Comment: *"continuing with the class"* makes no sense to me. Do you mean continuing executing the method code? Can you show that method/code?

Comment: @m0skit0 The do while loop is not looping after. Code is available here http://paste.revo.pw/uwavaxokek

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
Scanner myInput = new Scanner(system.in);

do {
    printMenuOption();
    if (!myInput.hasNextInt()){

        if(myInput.hasNextDouble()){

            System.out.println("You can not use a decimal number!");
            System.out.println("Please try again, choose a number from 1 to 10.");


        }else if(myInput.nextLine().length() <= 1){

            System.out.println("You can not use a character as an entry");
            System.out.println("Please try again, choose a number from 1 to 10.");


        }else if(myInput.nextLine().length() > 1){

            System.out.println("You can not enter a string");
            System.out.println("Please try again, choose a number from 1 to 10.");

        }
        else{

            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 1 to 10");
            userInput = myInput.nextLine();
        }



    }
    else{

        returnDataMenu(myInput.nextInt());
    }

} while (cont == true);
```

Comment: When you do `myInput.nextLine()` this actually reads the line so you can't call it more than once and expect it to return the same string. ALso when is the length not <= 1 or > 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Do as below it will solve your problem,

```
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
                if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    returnDataMenu(sc.nextInt());
                } else if (sc.hasNextLong()) {
                    System.out.println("You can't enter a long number, please use a whole number from 1-10");
                } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                    System.out.println("You can't enter a number with a decimal, please use a whole number from 1-10");
                } else if (sc.hasNextBoolean()) {
                    System.out.println("You can't enter a boolean, please use a whole number from 1-10");
                } else if (sc.next() != null) {
                    System.out.println("You can't enter a string, please use a whole number from 1-10");
                } else if (sc.nextLine().length() <= 1) {
                    System.out.println("You can't enter a char, please use a whole number from 1-10");
                }
}
```

java.util.Scanner has many hasNextXXX methods that can be used to validate input. below link have overview of all of them:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29